# store.getState is always returning the default state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have a react app with Oauth handled on the server by express and passport. I want to configure authentication based routing i.e. only certain routes must to available to browse without logging in otherwise navigating to those routes must redirect the user to the Login page.

So initially when the app loads(App.js), in the `componentDidMount` method I have called an API which fetches the user. If the user is returned it means he is logged in else he is logged out. Im using redux so this user gets stored in the redux store after an action is dispatched once the API is called.

I have an auth.js file where I am retrieving the state of the user, but it is always null and because of that its returning false. Why is this happening?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';



const store = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk),window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension() ));

export default store;

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import { BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/userActions';
import RouteAuthenticator from '../components/routes/routeAuthenticator';


class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                    <RouteAuthenticator path="/home/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

RouteAuthenticator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import isLoggedIn from '../../services/auth';

const RouteAuthenticator = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      isLoggedIn()
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/' />
    )} />
)

export default RouteAuthenticator;
```

auth.js

```
import store from '../index';

export default function isUserLoggedIn () {
    const state = store.getState();
    if (state.user) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: that is you're state is not being updated when the user is logged in. Where are you updating you state? after a successfull login you should update your state.

Comment: The fetchUser is updating the state. When I check the state in redux tools it shows me the updated state

Comment: you need to subscribe to the state
https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener

Comment: I think you're state is null as you're doing connect(null, actions) in app.. Check this link https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial#connecting-the-components

Comment: That null is for the mapStateToProps which I do not need in App.js